# Failed to make request in SOAP [Android 7.1.2] SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed ssl

Tags: java, android, ssl, soap

I am sending some data to a SOAP service, I am doing this with Java and Android, when I get to the part where I make the request, it gives me the following error:

```
2023-06-29 11:08:39.659 18904-19109/paquete D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2023-06-29 11:08:39.663 18904-19109/paquete I/DpmTcmClient: RegisterTcmMonitor from: com.android.okhttp.TcmIdleTimerMonitor
2023-06-29 11:08:40.343 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
2023-06-29 11:08:40.344 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:429)
2023-06-29 11:08:40.345 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectTls(Connection.java:235)
2023-06-29 11:08:40.346 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:199)
2023-06-29 11:08:40.347 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172)
2023-06-29 11:08:40.347 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:367)
2023-06-29 11:08:40.348 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:130)
2023-06-29 11:08:40.351 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
2023-06-29 11:08:40.352 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:247)
2023-06-29 11:08:40.352 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457)
2023-06-29 11:08:40.353 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:126)
2023-06-29 11:08:40.354 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:257)
2023-06-29 11:08:40.355 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
2023-06-29 11:08:40.356 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
2023-06-29 11:08:40.357 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.openOutputStream(ServiceConnectionSE.java:134)
2023-06-29 11:08:40.357 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.sendData(HttpTransportSE.java:295)
2023-06-29 11:08:40.358 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:184)
2023-06-29 11:08:40.359 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:118)
2023-06-29 11:08:40.360 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:113)
2023-06-29 11:08:40.360 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err:     at paquete.api.ApiRequestSOAP.requestSOAPSend(ApiRequestSOAP.java:152)
2023-06-29 11:08:40.361 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err:     at paquete.activity.apps.paqueteTransactionActivity$11$1$1.run(paqueteTransactionActivity.java:364)
2023-06-29 11:08:40.362 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
2023-06-29 11:08:40.364 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err:   Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
2023-06-29 11:08:40.365 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err:       ... 21 more
2023-06-29 11:08:40.369 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err:       Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
2023-06-29 11:08:40.369 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err:           ... 21 more
2023-06-29 11:08:40.371 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err:       Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0x8ae799c0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
2023-06-29 11:08:40.372 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err: error:1000042e:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:610 0x8bb040c0:0x00000001)
2023-06-29 11:08:40.372 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
2023-06-29 11:08:40.373 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:357)
2023-06-29 11:08:40.373 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err:           ... 20 more
2023-06-29 11:08:40.375 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err:   Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0x8ae799c0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
2023-06-29 11:08:40.376 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err: error:1000042e:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:610 0x8bb040c0:0x00000001)
2023-06-29 11:08:40.376 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
2023-06-29 11:08:40.377 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:357)
2023-06-29 11:08:40.377 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err:       ... 20 more
2023-06-29 11:08:40.380 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err: Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0x8ae799c0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
2023-06-29 11:08:40.380 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err: error:1000042e:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:610 0x8bb040c0:0x00000001)
2023-06-29 11:08:40.381 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
2023-06-29 11:08:40.381 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:357)
2023-06-29 11:08:40.382 18904-19109/paquete W/System.err:   ... 20 more
2023-06-29 11:08:40.382 18904-19109/paquete D/FormOperacionActivity: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
2023-06-29 11:08:40.394 18904-18904/paquete D/paqueteTransactionActivity: Error de conexión
2023-06-29 11:08:40.439 18904-18904/paquete V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@e4f5459
2023-06-29 11:08:40.440 18904-18904/paquete V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@950381e
```

The code I am using is the following:

```
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(SOAP_NAMESPACE, SOAP_METODE_SEND);

           
            String bodySend = ApiConfig.createBodySendSOAP(dato1, dato2, dato3, String.valueOf(dato4), dato5);
            request.addProperty("JsonIN", bodySend);

           
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            
            HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(urlSoapSend);
            httpTransport.debug = true;
            //setSSLFactory(httpTransport);
            
            //httpTransport.setReadTimeout(SOAP_REQUEST_TIMEOUT);

           
            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_SEND, envelope);

            
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

            
            result = response.toString();
```

And with this implementation
implementation 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.4'

It should be mentioned that if it works with operating systems to android 7

Try to test with TLSv1.2, TLSv1.0, TLSv1

And with this implementation implementation 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.4'

It should be mentioned that if it works with operating systems to android 7

Try to test with TLSv1.2, TLSv1.0, TLSv1